# How can wordpress themes save and retrieve settings?

Tags: wordpress

I'm programming a wordpress theme and need to make it save data, how should I have it do this? Is there a wordpress function or would I have to connect to the database on my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just trying to store simple name -> value pairs?

You could check for $_POST data in your theme then use `update_option($name,$value)` to save the data.

`update_option` will create the row in the DB if it doesn't exist. And get_option($name) will retrieve it.

Or are you trying to store something more complex?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of data you're trying to save, how you want it saved, and what you want to do with it later.  Can you be more specific?